# Check with JavaScript that JSEcoin mining is online or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mining, cryptocurrency

I embedded JSECoin's browser mining script to my website. It's a javascript based cryptocurrency miner script, that runs only on 100%, if the browser tab is in focus, and it doesn't eats the CPU, so it's much friendlier than other scripts.

At the first visit, the script shows a popup, that tells: mining is running on this site. Here is the first place, where you can deny it.
The second option to deny the mining is that you install an adblocker plugin to your browser.

When I can't (or don't want to) check both, there is only one option left: checking, that the mining is currently running or not? The script is sending messages to the console, eg:

- (index):1 Loaded
  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js
- (index):1 JSE Socket Connected!
- (index):1 JSE Data Received (500hps): [...hash...]

Is it possible to check, that the mining is running or not? I can't understand the JS code well.

There is a site for sample mining:
https://developer.jsecoin.com/API/#MinerCode

And a site to check it, with adblock solution:
https://jsecoin.com/misc/adblocker/demo.html

Thanks a lot!

I asked for it on the official FB page, but nothing answer. :/

```
<script>
  !function(){
    var e=document,
      t=e.createElement("script"),
      s=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];

    t.type="text/javascript",
    t.async=t.defer=!0,
    t.src="https://load.jsecoin.com/load/2895/jsecoin.com/optionalSubID/0/",
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)
  }();
</script>
```

Comment: *"doesn't eat cpu"* ... of course that's what they want you to believe. They wouldn't need to spread it all over the place if it wasn't intensive. Miners are draining batteries all over the globe

Comment: I compared the browser mining scripts, and I found this script the best. You can test it too, and compare with eg monero mining on this page, what mines for the UNICEF Australia: https://www.thehopepage.org/